# Zariski Topology and Euclidean Ball

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, zariski-topology

I don't understand why an open Euclidean ball is not open in the Zariski topology. I understand that there's a definition, but everything about the definition seems completely arbitrary.

I'm working through some topology right now, but I'm having difficulty understanding basic concepts or what's going on. My strength was never abstract algebra or anything of that kind. Anyways, I don't get the basic idea of a Zariski topology. What exactly is it supposed to be? What are we trying to do with it? I'm just confused and don't get anything. It seems like everything has just come out of nowhere for no reason.

I do not like algebra or other topics like it, but I realized I needed to learn some topology for my research. So I'm taking topology right now, but I'm really struggling to understand what's going on. The visual material that involves transformations or other things like that, I'm getting, but I do not understand all the other stuff. How the hell do I understand these basic concepts or ideas.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Just the ball stuff or an overview of the Zariski topology on $\Bbb C^n$ from scratch? Because the latter might be a little too broad, and its understanding requires a bit of algebraic knowledge.

Comment: I've got two questions. The first is why is the open Euclidean ball not open in the Zariski topology for $R^n$

The second is not an overview of the Zariski topology itself. I have the definitions, but I'm trying to figure out why we're doing this? What is the point of all these definitions? What's actually going on? Just basic stuff about the goals, objectives, etc.. It seems to me like none of this makes any sort of sense. It seems like something you pulled out of nowhere for no good reason at all.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the definitions of point set topology in general, or Zariski topology in particular? Outside of algebraic geometry you will have scant use of Zariski topology. My guess is that at this point it was described in your course to give you a weird topology to play with. Basically to test your grasp of the definitions.

Comment: I'm having trouble in general. I get that there's a certain definition, but what's it actually supposed to be? Why are we defining it this way? What's the purpose of all this? What are we actually trying to construct and why are we constructing it in this way? What are the goals and objectives of this?

Everything seems completely arbitrary and random. My question is primarily regarding the Zariski topology specifically, but it's also a general way to think about or understand the basic ideas or intentions.

Comment: What does the definition of a Zariski topology do? Why do we define it this way? Surely, there must be some sort of a reasoning or purpose for all this.

Answer (score 0):

We suppose the ground field is $C$ the field of complex numbers. An subset for the Zariski topology is the complementary of a closed subset which has the form $V(I)$ where $I$ is an ideal of $C[X_1,...,X_n]$. $I$ is generated by a finite number of polynomial functions. Thus $V(I)$ can't contain an open subset of $C^n$ as the complementary of the open ball unless it is $C^n$.

Comment: I understand the definition itself, but why are we doing this? What's actually going on? Intuitively, I'm completely lost.

Comment: I suggest the Wikipedia article Zariski Topology. When it mentions an affine space $ A^n$, think of the cases $A=R$ and $A=C$.

Answer (score 0):

A basis of the topology is the set open sets of the form $D(f)=\bigl\{\text{prime ideals }\mathfrak p \text{  which do not contain }f\bigr\}$, where $f$ is a polynomial in $\mathbf C[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. This topology in general is not Hausdorff.

Thus, roughly, we can say that in $\mathbf C^2$, a basic open set, is the complement of an algebraic (complex) curve. This clearly has very little to do with Euclidean open balls.

Comment: You mean it has very little in common with Euclidean balls. Good point.